# Migrating to HTTPS only, most media library links need updating?

Tags: media-library

I've been migrating customer WP installations to an SSL only server. For some reason some (but not all) of the media libraries seem to have gotten hard coded URLs involved. These are media objects that have been uploaded from the WP instance itself. If I look at them in the media library, the permalink shows up with the HTTPS address just fine, but most of the `File-URL` fields  still read with the HTTP address. This is after changing the site URL in the settings.

What do I need to do to these installations so all the media embedded in pages doesn't break?

Comment: I would run a plugin like [Velvet Blues Update URLs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/), and swap `http://domain/` to `https://domain/` - this will replace *all* instances in the entire database (and will also handle serialized data).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic No such luck. Running that plugin changed a whole pile of URLs for sure—thousands—but the `file-url` field on media items remains unchanged so I'm still having mixed content troubles.

Comment: Did you make sure all the checkbox options were ticked when you ran the plugin? Esp. the `guid` field?

Comment: Ok I just checked on my SSL install, and the URL field for an attachment is indeed non-https. However, this does not give me mixed content issues - both on the frontend & backend, all *actual* image links are HTTPS in the source.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic Interestingly enough it doesn't seem to be the SRC field that's messed up any more (it was). Now its the responsive image system and the SRCSET values that are not updating. The [force-https-srcset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-https-srcset/) plugin smooths that over, but it would be nice to just fix the DB somehow so they were all correct rather than having to continuously run a plugin to rewrite them at render time.

Comment: The issue won't be the db, it'll be a bug in the way the srcset URL's are calculated - although there is the `guid` field in the posts table, all URL's not hardcoded in the post content are generated at runtime, and should use the same protocol as the context. Will take a look and possibly file in trac.

Comment: I have the same issue, tried the Velvet Blues and sandr to replace the URLS, I didn't check the bottom option for updating the GUIDS and it seems to say DON"T ever do that. Anyways my URL's for images are still http:// * I ended up using Really Simple SSL plugin and it fixed my issues, but i hate running unnecessary plugins... which i feel this one is if you have all the code good.

Comment: I was having the same problem on my site. I moved from Http to https yesterday and have been testing my site since.
First use this tool to check if any SSL errors are happening https://www.jitbit.com/sslcheck/
Then Install Better search replace on Wordpress and make the changes in url from http to https. It works great and solves all the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I did (step 3 should probably solve your problem):

### 1. Update .htaccess File

Add the following to the .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

### 2. Update WordPress Site URL

Navigated to **Settings > General** and update the **WordPress Address (URL)** and **Site Address (URL)** to https.

### 3. Update Old http URLs

1. Install the plugin **Velvet Blues Update URLs**
2. Go to **Tools > Update URLs**
3. Enter Old and New URL, e.g. Old: **http**://www.example.com and New: **https**://www.example.com
4. Check all checkboxes and click Update URLs NOW
5. Repeat steps 3-4 but remove "www" this time, e.g. **http**://example.com and New: **https**://example.com

Comment: I have followed these directions to the letter, however when viewing the images in media library, opening up an image's details, the url field is still display in http://